# Pushing Objects into Array React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

### I'm struggling to get this to work.

I'm currently looping over each URL (fake ones for the sake of this test, I know they won't work).
Then I want to return each element into an object inside an array, then push it to the state so I can access it via the JSX.

productData returns undefined inside the getData, and if I remove the check and just run

```
setProductData([
  ...productData,
  {
    productName,
    productMainPrice,
    productSecondPrice,
    productQuantity,
    productAddToBag
  }
]);
```

It's the same effect.

I've even tried setting up another useState to capture the data:

```
setProduct({
  productName,
  productMainPrice,
  productSecondPrice,
  productQuantity,
  productAddToBag
});
setProductData([...productData, product]);
```

**My overall code:**

```
export const Component = async () => {
  const productPages = ["testURL", "testURL", "testURL", "testURL"];
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async urls => {
      urls.forEach(async url => {
        debugger;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const html = await response.text();
        const productPage = document.createElement("div");
        productPage.classList.add("hidden");
        productPage.id = "no-visual";
        productPage.innerHTML = html;

        productPage
          .querySelector('[data-test-id="main-price"]')
          .firstChild.remove();
        productPage
          .querySelector('[data-test-id="main-price"]')
          .lastChild.remove();
        productPage
          .querySelector('[data-test-id="second-price"]')
          .firstChild.remove();
        productPage
          .querySelector('[data-test-id="second-price"]')
          .lastChild.remove();

        const productName = productPage.querySelector(
          '[data-test-id="product-name"] h1'
        ).textContent;
        const productMainPrice = productPage.querySelector(
          '[data-test-id="main-price"]'
        ).textContent;
        const productSecondPrice = productPage.querySelector(
          '[data-test-id="second-price"]'
        ).textContent;
        const productQuantity = productPage.querySelector(
          '[data-test-id="button-wrapper"]'
        ).outerHTML;
        const productAddToBag = productPage.querySelector(
          '[data-test-id="button-wrapper"]'
        ).nextElementSibling.outerHTML;
        if (productData) {
          setProductData([
            ...productData,
            {
              productName,
              productMainPrice,
              productSecondPrice,
              productQuantity,
              productAddToBag
            }
          ]);
        }
        setProductData([
          {
            productName,
            productMainPrice,
            productSecondPrice,
            productQuantity,
            productAddToBag
          }
        ]);
      });
    };
    getData(productPages);
  }, []);

  console.log(productData);

  return (
    <div className="grid2x2">
      <div className="box box1">
        <div>
          <img src="" alt="" />
        </div>{" "}
        <div>
          <div>
            {" "}
            {productData[0].productName} {productData[0].productMainPrice}{" "}
            <span> EX VAT </span> {productData[0].productSecondPrice}{" "}
            {productData[0].productQuantity} {productData[0].productAddToBag}{" "}
            <span> INC VAT </span>{" "}
          </div>{" "}
        </div>{" "}
      </div>{" "}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your productData is initially undefined because you are not setting an initial state in useState. In this case, productData is false in the if clause and setProductData is not called.
Also I recommend using setState functions like this in this example: `setState(state => {/* do something with state */ return newState;})`

Comment: call this one before setproductData ,getData(productPages);
and add empty array in usesState